# Safe seaborn theme

Tags: python, seaborn

I recently discovered seaborn and saw there are many possible combinations of styles. At the moment, I am just using the default Seaborn configuration, to improve on matplotlib style to plot data (basically point series or graphs of functions, not really statistical data).

I discovered Seaborn thanks to [prettyplotlib](http://blog.olgabotvinnik.com/prettyplotlib/).

Has anyone already thought about a "safe" theme, which renders nicely to plot functions, and aims at rendering nicely for colorblind people or black and white printing?

Thanks

EDIT: I am currently experiencing with "hls" and "Set2" palettes. The later seems to be good for colorblindness, but render very poorly  in B&W I think. =(

Comment: Following your prettyplotlib link: the [ColorBrewer](http://colorbrewer2.org/#) suite helps you choose palettes which are color-blind and printing safe. These palettes are all supported by [Seaborn](https://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/tutorial/color_palettes.html?highlight=color%20brewer).

Comment: Sure, but when checking both "colorblind safe" and "photocopy safe" there are not much themes still available, and none with more than 4 colors. That is why I was willing to know if someone knew some nice looking full palette.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just came across [this blog post](http://www.ifweassume.com/2013/05/cubehelix-or-how-i-learned-to-love.html) about cubehelix which seems to be one of the best option for my use case. This is also available in seaborn: https://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.cubehelix_palette.html#seaborn.cubehelix_palette.

Answer (score 5):

If you're actually asking about which colormap to use, the authors of matplotlib recently did a [very good video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xAoljeRJ3lU) about their new default colormap, `viridis`. viridis is designed to be:

- Colorful
- Pretty
- Sequential
- Accurately represent the data ("Perceptually uniform")
- ...even if printed in black and white
- Accessible to colorblind viewers

It looks like this:

[image]

Comment: I found this one indeed, and it looks really cool. But most of the palettes I came across (including this one) seems to be designed to plot surfaces as 2D projection (that is colormap, but use the full colormap on the plot). Whereas I was looking for a palette to plot multiple functions on the same graph. I find this one not very good for this purpose as colors are very close. The best palettes I found so far are the ones based on cubehelix, and tableau10 and colorbrewer 10 colors qualitative palette.

Comment: Could you give me a better example of what you are looking for? Are you looking for a colorscheme that would for instance fit a plot of several lines? It looks like cubehelix would fit that.

Comment: Indeed, I am looking for a colorscheme. For now, the best one I found are cubehelix ones and https://tableaufriction.blogspot.fr/2012/11/finally-you-can-use-tableau-data-colors.html.

Comment: You will often find that the colorscheme you are looking for is dependent on how many lines you need to plot. The more lines you're plotting, the more similar the colors of those lines become. Something like `color_list = plt.cm. cubehelix(np.linspace(0, 1, nLines))` where nLines is the number of lines you will be plotting. That should divide the colorscheme into colors as far "apart" as possible.

Comment: I would also recommend checking out [this detailed post](https://bids.github.io/colormap/) that discusses the new mpl colormaps (inc. the mpl v0.2 default of viridis) as well as the existing ones.